# Are regular languages closed under sort (Parikh image)?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Assume $L$ is a regular language over an ordered alphabet.  Is the language built by taking every word in $L$ and sorting it always a regular language?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Counterexample: assuming $a < b$, we have $(ab)^\ast \xrightarrow{\;\;\text{sorted}\;\;} \{ a^n b^n \;|\; n \geqslant 0 \}$, which cannot be expressed by a regular expression, by the [pumping lemma for regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).